# How I can upload videos from my iPhone with PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I want the user to be able to upload video files to my site from iPhone.

my PHP is here:

```
 <?php

$allowedExts = array("jpg", "JPG", "jpeg", "JPEG", "gif", "GIF", "png", "PNG", "mp4", "MP4", "mov", "MOV");
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// RANDOM Code
function name_file($length = 20) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

$name_file = name_file();
// END RANDOM Code

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/MP4")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mov")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/MOV")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/JPEG")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/GIF")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/PNG")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/JPG")
)
```

The code is work with all extensions except iPhone extension "mov".
Thanks for help :)

Comment: Your code seems broken - the `if` part is incomplete, nothing uses `$allowedExts`, etc. Maybe you'd want to review the question and update your code example.

Comment: if the answer below works for you, please mark it as approved?

Comment: @Guss still working on the if part :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented in [Apples developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone.html) the MIME type (what PHP calls `$_FILES["file"]["type"]`) is `video/quicktime`.